# Вывести два toast один за другим

Tags: android

Как вывести два toast: показывается один и гаснет, затем показывается другой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) и postDelayed(). Первый Toast показываем напрямую, а второй запускаем через postDelayed. Где то так

```
Toast.makeText(c, "before", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(c, "after", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
      }
    }, 1500);
```

Только вместо 1500 (это 1.5 секунды) впишите свое значение, подобранное эмпирическим путем.

Comment: А разве два тоста не отработают один за другим если их подряд написать?

Comment: Вроде первый отработает быстро и сразу будет второй. Но нужно проверить.

Comment: @KoVadim - 
Только что проверил, вызовы

        Toast.makeText(this, "One", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Two", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

отработали оба как и написано, LONG.